# at+cifsr get IP connect Internet via Python

Tags: python, gsm, at-command

I have a problem.
I am writing a gsm module add-on in Python.
How can I set the received IP address as the default address?
On Linux.

```
def check_network():
    for i in range(1, 3):
        if send_at("AT+CGREG?", "0,1") == 1:
            print('SIM868 is online\r\n')
            break
        else:
            print('SIM868 is offline, please wait...\r\n')
            utime.sleep(5)
            continue
    send_at("AT+CPIN?", "OK")
    send_at("AT+CSQ", "OK")
    send_at("AT+COPS?", "OK")
    send_at("AT+CGATT?", "OK")
    send_at("AT+CGDCONT?", "OK")
    send_at("AT+CSTT?", "OK")
    send_at("AT+CSTT=\""+APN+"\"", "OK")
    send_at("AT+CIICR", "OK")
    send_at("AT+CIFSR", "OK")
```

AT+CIFSR command gives the ip address.

Comment: "the default address"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How is `send_at` implemented (please, edit it into the question)? As far as I understand (though it is not clear what is the default address you are talking about) you want to get the IP returned by `AT+CIFSR`... but you don't get `send_at` return value (if it has one), so that's no way to get the info you can get from that command (supposing you are parsing its response)